# What are the features of Honeycomb Room on Coulson's bus?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

Since the beginning of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, I see that Coulson and team always lock criminals, supernaturals and aliens (even if its first encounter with that alien), etc in a *Honeycomb Kill Room* (in words of Talbot) on the Bus (Coulson's Boeing Jet).

What are the features of this Honeycomb Room? Is there anything alien involved with it which gives them confidence over its features?

Comment: Ward describes it as vibranium-lined, iirc. Not quite alien, but it must give them some confidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing alien, as far as I know, but the top-of-the-line Earth-based technology.

The honeycomb room you're talking about is the Bus's interrogation room, more frequently called "The Cage", and is the holding cell/interrogation room for anyone Coulson's team encounters while The Bus is out in the field. It has several features that make it suitable for holding the kinds of enemies that SHIELD typically finds:

- The walls are made of an alloy of silicon carbide and vibranium (according to Ward), making them strong enough to withstand physical assault by most alien creatures. For example, The Cage has been used to hold Asgardians against their will.
- According to the Bus blueprints, this material is called "EMS Isolation Baffling", which would also imply that the walls block electromagnetic signals in or out.
- At one point, Fitz installed additional magnetic shielding around The Cage that was designed to prevent extra-dimensional intrusion into the room.

Also, as a last resort, the Cage is located at the top of the plane, and has an airlock in the ceiling. This allows SHIELD to eject the contents of the room into the atmosphere in cases of extreme emergency.

Finally, on a more mundane note, the room seems to be a bit modular; depending on why they're using it, the furniture changes, but whatever's in the room seems to be attached to the walls and floors (e.g. the interrogation table, the bunks, etc.)