# Why did Skye use Honeycomb Room on Coulson's Bus?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In the last episode S02E14 of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Skye try to use Honeycomb Room on Coulson's Bus. Okay, [the Honeycomb Room gives some confidence against aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83807/what-are-the-features-of-honeycomb-room-on-coulsons-bus), but wasn't Skye's powers beyond comprehension? Talking about the confidence, in the episode S02E13, the same Honeycomb Room failed to contain Skye's powers. Then, why did Skye try to demolish precious Boeing Jet? And, why didn't anyone try to stop her?

Comment: At a guess: although it couldn't contain her powers at full strength, it would probably contain them longer than anywhere else. It gives her more time to calm down before she can do significant damage.

Comment: It should be noted that Skye did not TRY to demolish The Bus. At this point, she has no control over the powers and it seems to be completely tied to her emotional state.

Comment: @Omegacron Understand the sense, bro. Ofcourse, her motive wasn't the demolition of the bus, but if she knew that her powers weren't in control and still she went there, it means it was a silly move. That's what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first go over the possible places she *could* go.

- Her own personal room in the base. Probably the most comfortable place of the selected areas. This room is the least secure of her options.
- Her own personal room on the Bus. For all intents and purposes, equal to her personal room in the base.
- The prison cell where Ward was kept. Skye initially runs here during the events of S02E12 (*What You Are*). Lady Sif is able to break through the containment field, and as she does, you can hear and audible short-circuiting sound. Lady Sif *may* have badly damaged the system at that point (granted, with Fitz, Simmons and Mack all still on base at that point, it should be fixable). Of note, this cell is in the lowest level of the base. Creating an earthquake emanating from this point in the base is probably the most dangerous of anywhere.
- "the honeycomb room" located on the Bus. Similarly secure as the prison cell, but with the added benefit of being higher in the base (it has to be close to the surface or above ground) and within a vehicle designed to shake a bit. Since Skye can consciously work to localize her powers to a degree of success, she could minimize damage done by shaking the Bus (which could still be catastrophic).

So, of these four, the Bus is probably the best bet - but not by much.

But we're ignoring context, and a possibly more important out-of-universe reason.

At the end of *What You Are*, Skye packs her bags and moves into " the honeycomb room". She's not only feeling afraid of her powers, but most of the team is afraid of her and just expressed that she may not be welcome anymore. She wants to get as far away from everyone as possible - for everyone's sake. No one stopped her because frankly, I think most people are relieved she's out of sight.

And most importantly, I think, is the term she used. She doesn't call it "the honeycomb room"; **she calls it "the cage".**

This ties back into her feeling ostracized, and thematically makes a huge point. She feels inhuman, like an animal, meant to be locked up in a cage. Where better for her character to temporarily reside?

Comment: Actually, "The Cage" is the proper name for the room she's in, so I wouldn't read too much into that. But you're also right that she's putting herself in the prison cell/interrogation room, where all of the other dangerous people are put. It may not be able to contain her, but it's more likely than any other room in the base.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield It is, but I still think the theme of putting herself into "the cage" is relevant to the writers.